# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'useSyncExternalStore')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Whenever I run my code it runs my DisplayProductsOnLoad(), it calls the function getAllProducts() in test.js that retries all products in the database. However, getAllProducts is being called 4 times. DisplayAllProductsApp() is being called 4 times by the render function and I do not know why. I also get the Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'useSyncExternalStore') that has something to do with react query as well it seems.

index.js

```js
// index.js

import { getAllProducts } from "../../test.js";
const { useQuery, QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } = window.ReactQuery;

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

function DisplayProductsOnLoad(props) {    
    console.log("Hello 2");
    
    const { data, error, isLoading } = useQuery(["getAll"], getAllProducts(), {
        refetchOnWindowFocus: false
    });

    if (error) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + error);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Data from index.js: ", data);
    }

    return (
        // Div where products are displayed in
        <div class="row p-3" style={{ backgroundColor: "white", borderRadius: "10px" }} id="product-list">
            Hello World
        </div>
    );
}


function DisplayProductsOnLoadApp(props) {
    console.log("Hello 1");

    return (
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
            <DisplayProductsOnLoad product={props.product}/>
        </QueryClientProvider>
    );
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    console.log("start");
    const product = { productImage: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/842711/pexels-photo-842711.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2", productName: "obfwofnofndofnpasnfasipfpasifnasfnasfapsifaspifasnfasin", productPrice: 20.99 }

    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('#allProductsDisplay'));
    root.render(<DisplayProductsOnLoadApp product={product} />);
});
```

test.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>test.html</title>

        <!----------------------------------------For Card------------------------------------------------>
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css" />
        <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
        
        <!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="general.css" />



        <!---------------------------------React------------------------------------------>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

        <!---------------------------------React Query------------------------------------------>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@tanstack/react-query@4.0.0/build/umd/index.production.js"></script>

        <!---------------------------------Display product Cards (All Products)------------------------------------------>
        <script src="./compiled/General/index.js" type="module"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid" style="width: 98%" id="allProductsDisplay"></div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

test.js

```js
// test.js

const STORAGE_API_HOST = `http://localhost:3000`;

export function getAllProducts() {
    console.log("Hello back end")
    // const url = new URL(`/products`, STORAGE_API_HOST);
    const url = `${STORAGE_API_HOST}/products`;
    return fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => {
      console.log("Data: ", json.rows);
      return json.rows;
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log("Error: " + error))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of `useQuery` should be a function. So just pass `getAllProducts` instead of calling it. See [docs](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/reference/useQuery?from=reactQueryV3&original=https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/reference/useQuery).

```
const { data, error, isLoading } = useQuery(["getAll"], getAllProducts, {
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false
});
```